# How to use "if not equal" with multiple items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a basic question, but I was wondering how to do something like:

*If `i` doesn't equal 1 or 2 or 3 then `alert('yes');`*

Can we do it like:

```
if (!(i==1&2&3)) { alert('yes')}
```

Instead of:

```
if (!((i==1) || (i==2) || (i ==3) )) { alert('yes');}
```

Comment: No you can't, surely you could have just tried it and got the answer?

Comment: If `i` is number > 0 and not decimal, you can use `if (i >= 4) {alert('yes')}` :-)

Comment: @Biffen: _If i doesn't equal 1 or 2 or 3 then alert('yes');_ There is no problem with 3.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), but I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve?

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        break;
    default:
        alert(yes);
}
```

Or even a lookup table,something like this.

```
var x = {
    1: true,
    2: true,
    3: true
};

if (!x[i]) {
    alert('yes');
}
```

But if you want to be strict about it and have so few tests to perform, then there is probably nothing better than.

```
if (i !== 1 && i !== 2 && i !== 3) {
    alert('yes');
}
```

Comment: As a side note, `switch` does use strict comparison.

Comment: That's correct and neither does the lookup table, I perhaps did not make that clear enough even though I mention strictness. But it really depends on what the Op is trying to achieve and that is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array and use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
if([1,2,3].indexOf(i) < 0){
    alert('yes');
}
```

if the result is greater than `-1`, it means `i` is one of those values.

I dont think

```
if (!(i=1&2&3)) { alert('yes')}
```

will work(according to your goals) because `1&2&3` is bitwise **AND**. Also, you are using one `=` operator

Comment: I think he doesn't want to match. So the condition will be `< 0`

Comment: @VinodKumar, even if you were. I dont mind. I DO mind when people downvote without saying anything! However, you did tell me why, so thank you!

Comment: @AmmarCSE: Surely you already know what the downvote is for? Vinod commented and 2 people upvoted his comment... no point downvoter repeating what has already been said. I was the first downvoter, but I have since removed mine due to the correction, but not all users will stick around on a question waiting to see if it gets fixed. If you are going to rush your answer then that is the risk you take